# IllegalFormatConversionException d != java.lang.Integer when trying to printf date?

Tags: java, date, printf

```
public void display() {
    System.out.printf("%-10d%-12s%-12s%10.2f%8d%12.2f%1$td.%1$tm.%1$ty %n\n",
    this.getID(),
    this.getFirstName(),
    this.getLastName(),
    this.getState(),
    this.getNo(),
    this.getAmt(),
    this.getDate());
}
```

Is my method for printing out some of my info. `this.getDate` returns date as a Date (java.util.Date) type.

I had an example given to me as `System.out.printf("%1$td.%1$tm.%1$ty %n", date);` to print out the data in a `dd.mm.yyyy` format. I tried to place that into my code, but by the looks of things I made a formatting mistake?

I've been trying a few printing methods now but find it confusing how it would work on its own but then I have issues when I try to place it into a larger printf statement.

Comment: Try converting it to a String and then printing it out as a string instead of an integer.

Comment: It won’t solve your present issue, but I recommend you don’t use  `java.util.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the number before the $-sign indicates the absolute index (starting with 1! ) of the Object. You intended to point at the Date (Index 7) but pointed at the first element instead, which happend to be an Integer. You'll want to use `"%-10d%-12s%-12s%10.2f%8d%12.2f%7$td.%7$tm.%7$ty %n\n"` for formatting.

Comment: Even better would be `"%-10d%-12s%-12s%10.2f%8d%12.2f%td.%<tm.%<ty %n"`, since absolute argument indexes are easily broken if the arguments change.  (Also, `%n` is a newline, so an additional `\n` is probably redundant.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all Date formatting is a complex issue and is already dealt with for you. So you trying to come up your own formatter (such as "%-10d%-12s%-12s%10.2f%8d%12.2f%td.%toString() of class `Date`. If you need better formatting than look at method [DateFormat.format(Date date)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-). However, note that if you use Java 8 or higher than the class `java.util.Date` shouldn't be used. Look at `java.time` package. Use [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) or any of its "brothers" instead of `Date` and use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to format it to string